# My custom javascript replace method for Fancybox and Vimeo works on some pages, but not all

Tags: 7, javascript

So, I have beent tackling this issue since yesterday to no avail. I have been trying to integrate Vimeo videos into Drupal 7 and display them in a nice Fancybox overlay. I am using the following Modules in combination to try and achieve this: Semantic Fields, Field Collections, Custom Filter, and Fancybox.

I needed the videos to be inline with sections of Book content, so I originally wrote a custom filter that looked for [vimeo=1234]Video Title[/vimeo] in the body input and converted it into a link where the embedded player was in a div that would pop out as a fancybox. The custom script takes the original expression and finds the relevant data to create this. I later made a regular expression that looked for the custom field I created, which worked like a link and allowed the user to paste the complete vimeo url. I thought that method might be easier for the user inputing content, and the way multiple custom fields are rendered in their own div container also makes it easier for me to style in CSS (which was giving me problems with the [vimeo] inline tag method).

Here is the method that embeds the fancybox vimeo player. It's based on this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4285098/1475099) solution, which helped me get thumbnails to work:

```
    function vimeoLoadingThumb(id, title, obj){    

    var url = "http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/" + id + ".json?callback=showThumb";

    var filtered_fancy = '<div class="section gallery clearfix" id="gallery_'+id+'"><a data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="#vimeo_' + id + '" rel="lightbox"><img id="vimeo-' + id +'" \/><br\/>'+ title +'<\/a><\/div><div style="display:none"><div id="vimeo_'+ id +'"><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="281" mozallowfullscreen="" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'+ id +'\" webkitallowfullscreen="" width="500"><\/iframe><\/div><\/div>';

    if(obj){
        jQuery(obj).before(filtered_fancy);
        jQuery(obj).remove();

    }else {
    document.write(filtered_fancy);

     }


    var id_img = "#vimeo-" + id;
    var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    jQuery(id_img).before(script);


    var element =  jQuery('gallery_'+id).clone();


}
```

The obj parameter is only used when the original content to be replaced comes from the custom fields. While I got my [vimeo] tag to work exactly the way I wanted, I am having trouble using my custom fields! I am seeing the same kinds of warning messages on both methods of insertion, but only the [vimeo] tag fancyboxes work. Clicking the custom field links do not fire any javascript events. I compared the source codes between the two, as well, and I can see no real differences. I also know that both methods are playing nicely with the Vimeo API because I use the vimeo API to display the vimeo thumbnails and those show up, no problem.

Here are the warnings I am seeing for both approaches:

```
event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future.
```

and

```
event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future.
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "http://a.vimeocdn.com/p/1.4.21/fonts/vimeo.woff". 33364975:1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can ignore the first error (`event.layerX...`), it's a known issue with webkit and should be fixed in a later release. It won't be affecting your code

Comment: I've been ignoring it, as it shows up on pretty much every page!  However, is there any logical reason to explain why my code works with the [vimeo] tag and not the custom field?